# Second call to HttpClient's PostAsJsonAsync stucks

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to post some data to a web service and receive response with HttpClient in a console application. If I try to reuse a HttpClient instance, the first call to PostAsJsonAsync works as expected, but the second just waits forever. If i create a new HttpClient for every call then everything is OK.

```
public class DirectHandler
{
    HttpClient httpClient;

    public string SendToPlayer(object message)
    {

        if (httpClient == null)
        {
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("..url...");
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("", message).Result;  // Blocking call!
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException("Error code " + response.StatusCode + ", reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

The code using this class:

```
DirectHandler dh = new DirectHandler();
var resp = dh.SendToPlayer(myObj);
Console.WriteLine("Received: " + resp);
Thread.Sleep(500);
resp = dh.SendToPlayer(myObj);
Console.WriteLine("Received: " + resp);
```

The "server" is a HttpListener:

```
public class HTTPServer
{
    void StartListener()
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("my prefix");
        listener.Start();
        listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(OnRequestReceive), listener);
    }

    private void OnRequestReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;

        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, request.ContentEncoding))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }

        string responseString = "{'a': \"b\"}";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(OnRequestReceive), listener);
    }
}
```

How can i reuse HttpClient?

**Update:**
I changed .Result to async/await, now the SendToPlayer method looks like this:

```
public async Task<string> SendToPlayer(object message)
{
    if (httpClient == null)
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("..url...");
    }

    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("", message).ConfigureAwait(false); 
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpRequestException("Error code " + response.StatusCode + ", reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

It still waits forever in PostAsJsonAsync when called more than once.

**Update2:**

The test code, hangs on the second SendToPlayer line:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        DirectHandler dh = new DirectHandler();
        var resp = await dh.SendToPlayer(myObj);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: " + str);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        resp = await dh.SendToPlayer(myObj);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: " + str);

    }).Wait();
}
```

Comment: When using async/await do not wait for an async method using .Result or .Wait(), always use `await`. Depending on the environment en context .Result and .Wait can result to deadlocks.

Comment: I rewritten my code to use await instead of .Result everywhere, but nothing changed. I also tried .PostAsJsonAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false), but the second call to it still hangs.

Comment: Show how you rewrote the code so we can see what you did.

Comment: The code that uses the class now shows `var resp = dh.SendToPlayer(myObj);`, this should be awaited too: `var resp = await dh.SendToPlayer(myObj);`. The method calling that piece of code needs to be awaited as well all the way up.

Comment: Changed that too, updated the question with the test code.

Comment: Which specific line does the debugger stop on if you hit pause? You may need to open the "Threads" window to switch to the background thread. Also give us a screenshot of your "Tasks" window when paused.

Comment: Might also be worth getting the call stacks of each of the Threads too.

Comment: Does the second HTTP POST get sent to your server or does it freeze first without actually being sent? Try running Fiddler to see if it is being sent and see if the responses are different between the first POST and second POST. Fiddler doesn't capture localhost traffic by default, so if your URI contains "localhost", add a period so that it is "localhost.", and Fiddler will start capturing the HTTP traffic.

Comment: Just use WebRequest ( WebRequest.Create(URL); ) directly , Its more lightweight and HttpClient uses it internally

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but notice that the code you provided doesn't even compile. Like where does `myObj` in your main method come from? And how do you even start the http listener since the method `StartListener` is declared private?
These kind of issues make me suspect that the code you've posted is not the actual code that has the described problem.

Also, what do you put into `myObj`?

I copied and adjusted your code to make it work on my machine. Please take a look to see if it runs on your machine as well in a new console app (you'll need administrator permissions to run it)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = new HTTPServer();
    s.StartListener();

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var myObj = 8;

        DirectHandler dh = new DirectHandler();
        var resp = await dh.SendToPlayer(myObj);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: " + resp);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        resp = await dh.SendToPlayer(myObj);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: " + resp);

    }).Wait();
}

public class HTTPServer
{
    public void StartListener()
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");
        listener.Start();
        listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(OnRequestReceive), listener);
    }

    private void OnRequestReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;

        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, request.ContentEncoding))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }

        string responseString = "{'a': \"b\"}";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(OnRequestReceive), listener);
    }
}

public class DirectHandler
{
    HttpClient httpClient;

    public async Task<string> SendToPlayer(object message)
    {
        if (httpClient == null)
        {
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080");
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("", message).ConfigureAwait(false); 
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException("Error code " + response.StatusCode + ", reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

this outputs

```
8
Received: {'a': "b"}
8
Received: {'a': "b"}
```

Now, you might have simplified your code posted here. If there is any code you've not posted here it will be hard to solve.

Is your `HttpListener` running in a separate (console) app? Maybe the server process is terminated after the first call, due to an error for example.

If the above code works in a new console app try to find the differences with your code.

Comment: myObj is a simple DTO, but now i'm using a single integer too. Your code works for me too. Originally my StartListener was public, probably deleted it accidentally during formatting. My DirectHandler is exactly like yours, and the main method too. The server doesn't stops after the first call (it's in an Unity3D application (maybe something here?), StartListener called on startup), if i restart the client it responds to the first request again, but the OnRequestReceive not triggered by the second PostAsJsonAsync. As i sad, if i create a new HttpClient in every SendToPlayer call, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, there are two issues:

1) your server needs to wait around to process more than only one event, and

2) your client and server code should reside in separate execution threads.

Based on the way you've written it, the server will shut down shortly after starting up, which is why maybe the first request works but the second one hangs.

I've created an example:
https://github.com/paulsbruce/StackOverflowExamples/tree/master/SOF40934218

You have to kick the server project off first, which waits for incoming requests (StartListening doesn't hold the server thread open, so there is a while(IsRunning) { Thread.Sleep(100); } loop as an example.
https://github.com/paulsbruce/StackOverflowExamples/blob/master/SOF40934218/SOF40934218_Server/Server.cs

Then kick off the client as a separate process and watch it's console output. It does in fact get a second response (why there is a 5 second delay to allow you to see this). 
https://github.com/paulsbruce/StackOverflowExamples/blob/master/SOF40934218/SOF40934218_Client/Client.cs

Hope these two suggestions help!